# AppEngineFile to byte[]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

How to convert AppEngineFile to an array of bytes?

I have my File created from the blobkey like this

```
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(new BlobKey("blob key"));
```

I already tried something like this

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

// Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(new BlobKey(video.getBlobkey()));

BlobstoreInputStream b = new BlobstoreInputStream(new BlobKey(video.getBlobkey()));

RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file.getFullPath(), "r");
byte[] pixels = b.read(); //doesn't work
```

The idea is to send this array of bytes with a POST request.

Here is my code i have to build the request:

```
String attachmentName = "test";
String attachmentFileName = "test.mp4";
String crlf = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/server.cgi");
httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
request.writeBytes(crlf);

// Get a file service
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
// Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(new BlobKey(video.getBlobkey()));

BlobstoreInputStream b = new BlobstoreInputStream(new BlobKey(video.getBlobkey()));

RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file.getFullPath(), "r");
byte[] pixels = b.read();

request.write(pixels);

request.writeBytes(crlf);
request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

request.flush();
request.close();

InputStream responseStream = new    BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
String line = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
}
responseStreamReader.close();

String response = stringBuilder.toString();
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
FileReadChannel ch = fileservice.openReadChannel(file, true);
byte[] data = getBytes(Channels.newInputStream(ch));
```

and use this handy method (useable elsewhere):

```
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int len;
    byte[] data = new byte[100000]; // adapt buffer size to your needs
    while ((len = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, len);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I tried [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/attachmentText?id=7862&aid=78620002000&name=fragment&token=ZhHB7_ZD-eR18jvUurfhpNCNnCI%3A1361371852297) and it blocked.

Comment: @JeromeAnsia When `is.read(data, 0, data.length) == -1` you have reached end of stream. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The input stream is empty with both your solution and the one of Javier :/

Comment: Then your blob is empty. Check in Blob Viewer. Or possibly you are catching `Exception` and your code silently fails before.

Comment: Also, `getBlobFile(..)` does not create a new blob - it retrieves an existing blob from blobstore. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService

Answer (score 2):

```
AppEngineFile file = ...

int size = (int) fileservice.stat(file).getLength().longValue();

    FileReadChannel ch = fileservice.openReadChannel(file, true);
    ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    try {
        int sum=0;
        while (sum<size) {
           int read = ch.read(dst);
           sum+=read;
        }
    } finally {ch.close();}

    bytes byte[] = dst.array();
```

(This is NOT the way of reading from a Channel in Java, but it seems there is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7862) in appengine that requires you know the exact count of bytes).

Comment: is resp HTTPServletResponse?

Comment: Set the status code to 200 (OK)... It is the default status code, so it should be the same if you remove that line.

Comment: Yes, it it HTTPServletResponse

Comment: ok thanks just one last question where you have the array of bytes at the end of the loop? Because i see byte array[] = dst.array(); so at each iteration you lose the previous bytes no?

Comment: oh ok you write them in the response, ok i don't do this exactly i send them in a POST request at the end but i think i can get something working with your code, thank you

Comment: I fixed the code so that the blob is read in a byte array. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The bug you are referring to happens when reading text files because `BufferedReader.readLine` does not detect end of file properly when reading from sockets. This is a known java problem, not a GAE bug - google it. Reading binary data works without a problem - workaround with `size` is not necessary.

Comment: I think one is supposed to read the channel while read!=-1 (http://books.google.com/books?id=925anNJ1cFsC&lpg=PA182&ots=BsU4lm3MdG&dq=java%20read%20from%20byte%20channel%20until%20eof&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q=java%20read%20from%20byte%20channel%20until%20eof&f=false)(), but GAE `FileReadChannel.read()` will return 0.

BTW, I've been reading from sockets for years using `BufferedReader` and it never blocked... perhaps I was lucky, or it is platform related. I will investigate, thanks.

Comment: This solution give me a 415 Unsupported Media Type from the received server

Comment: You should add a Content-Type `HTTPHeader` in the request. The Content-Type may be set to a fixed value (if you know that the files have some filetype, or that the web service accept an specific media type), or you may set the Content-Type that has been stored with the blob (see `BlobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo`). Note that loading a blob info consumes a datastore read.

Comment: @Javier: for example: http://www.coderanch.com/t/371268/java/java/BufferedReader-readLine-file

Comment: (int) fileService.stat(appEngineFile).getLength().longValue() is 0 actually